# How to use @media in CSS ONLY when user is using Zoom Text Only?

Tags: html, css

I have a page where I have some CSS @media fixes for when user Zoom Text Only (using firefox) to make the page look nicer (labels and boxes don't cross etc.). However, when I deselect zoom text only and zooms in it seems my @media fixes gets called (as expected since it is watching width). My question is is there a way to for the @media only get triggered when user is Zoom text only? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Generally one just allows "Zoom Text Only" to break a website, because those using it generally know it's going to happen and are used to it. (Either that, or hard-set your font sizes with px/etc in places they'd break, and not allow "Zoom Text Only" to even function there)